# SslStream error: Stream was not writable

Tags: c#, ssl, argumentexception, sslstream

I'm facing a strange error. Following code is always throwing exception (System.ArgumentException "`Stream was not writable`"):

```
TcpClient socket = new TcpClient();
socket.Connect("serverIp", serverPort);
//wrap networkstream with ssl 
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(socket.GetStream(),false); 

stream.ReadTimeout = 5000;
stream.WriteTimeout = 5000;

//following line throws System.ArgumentException "Stream was not writable"
var writer = new BinaryWriter(sslStream); 
writer.Write(abMessage, nStart, nLength);
writer.Flush();
```

'`sslStream`' object `canWrite` and `canRead` properties are always '`false`'.

Obviously, I have Googled, and searched in many forums, but, I always found that same code which is not working for me.

How can I fix this exception?

Answer (score 4):

Once you create a `SslStream`  (on top of a `TcpClient`) you should handshake the ssl connection. For this, you will use some of the methods available in the `SslStream` type:

- **`AuthenticateAsClient`** (several overloads)
- **`AuthenticateAsServer`** (several overloads)

(or they async variants `BeginAuthenticateAs...`)

Without using this handshaking methods the `SslStream` is not really setup and you won't be able to read or write from/to the network stream.

Which methods to use (`AuthenticateAsClient` or `AuthenticateAsServer`) is specific to your implementation and the desired usage of the SSL Stream.